# JBoss error deployment wildfly 10.x

Tags: hibernate, jboss, wildfly, ear

Here is the stack trace of my EAR deployment that I cant understand,could you help me, please ?

edit: My whole log http://pastebin.com/nqm0T9tc. Sorry it's limited to 30000 characters

Thanks !

Comment: the log you posted is incomplete. Please post the whole log. There must be a missing resource.

Comment: I edited my first post.

Comment: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/beans/Client you have to fix that

Comment: You seem to be creating classes in the java.* package. This package is reserved for the Java implementation and you will have lots of trouble unless you rename it.

Comment: Thank you guys ! That helps me a lot !